# Changing the color of a screen using Action bar activity selection

Tags: android

I am creating an application that is aimed at dyslexic children and i need to be able to allow the user to change the background color of the screen for things like reading books etc.

Currently the page defaults to a light yellow color (the most common color for dyslexic students) but I need options for blue, green and purple. 
I am wanting to use the action bar activity as i am already using this for editing and deleting items - so i need it to match the rest of the application.

What is the best way to do this?

Do i have to create the .xml file with the background colors that i want, and then call them? Or is there a way to set the background color in the page code itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could tackle this is by creating a Preference Settings that will allow the user to choose a color. Then, you can save the color that they selected inside the SharedPreferences and use it throughout your app unless the user decides to change the color again. If you don't save the color that they have chosen, then they're going to have to change the color every single time they open your app which is not desirable. You wont need to create an xml file or anything like that. Just get the color code stored inside your SharedPreferences and then apply it to your layout inside your onCreate() method. For example:

```
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String colorValue= sharedPreferences.getString("color", "#ffffff");
    int colorAsInt = Color.parseColor(colorValue);
    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(colorAsInt);
```

Comment: The app will be used by mulitple users on the same device (for use in a school) so the page will be changed depending on the needs of the child that is using it, so this method isn't quite appropriate for what i have at the moment.... However, there are profiles that are created for each child, so it might make sense to have a preference set up on their profile page and the color passed through to the pages  so that it only needs set up once... thank you, this is very helpful

Comment: In that case, you can omit the SharedPreferences part and create buttons or icons that represent the colors that you want. Then you could attach onClick() listeners to them and change the background of the layout to the color associated with the icon that was clicked.

Comment: Could i set it up as a preference when the child profile is created, store that in the database, pass it through to the appropriate activity and then set the background color accordingly?

Comment: You could definitely do that. In fact, if you are going to have to store structured data(like a user/child profile) then databases are the way to go. By the way, is the app going to be installed on only one device and accessed by multiple users on the same device?

Comment: Yeah, one device with multiple users. It's for teachers who work with children 1-1 so each teacher will have one device that they will use with multiple children. (it's for my final year university project - I'm just adding the final changes/features before my project defence meeting next week)

Comment: Hey, just wondering. See the way you have the `RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);` - how do i do that with the setContentView / a R.layout file? Is that possible? Or do i have to create a dummy XML file (that will override the original background colour?) Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot apply a background color to the layout file itself. You're going to have to apply it to the **root** element of your layout. In my case, it was the RelativeLayout. In your case, it could be a LinearLayout. You're going to have to get a reference to the **root** view of your layout file like I did with RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); and then set the background color to it. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say here.

Comment: Ah right okay. I have this so far: 
`setContentView(R.layout.student_profile_page);
        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);`
But i'm getting a 'cannot resolve symbol' message on the R.id.relativeLayout but and I'm not really sure what I have to do....

Comment: Inside your R.layout.student_profile_page layout file, do you have a RelativeLayout as the root or parent element(the one at the top of your layout file)? If not, you probably have a LinearLayout. And, it probably has some id attached to it too. You need to use that id inside findViewById(). If you have a RelativeLayout, then change it's id to android:id="@+id/relativeLayout". If it has no id, then add it yourself. If it is a LinearLayout, then you need to do the same thing, except this time it's going to be LinearLayout mLinearLayout=...you get the idea. Try it out.

Comment: It's a relative layout, and Yeah... adding the ID would have been a good idea... sorry, i haven't slept haha! 
Sorry! And thank you, that worked!

Comment: Haha. No problem. I know how projects can be! Anyway, I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change background color then take the reference of View in which you are setting default color.

```
View view=findViewById(R.id.backgroundView);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#987789"));
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the themes for your application, If you change your change your theme in settings then background color will automatically reflected to all other activities.
for more reference [click here](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/changing-your-android-apps-theme-dynamically.html)